# Installing Comsol from iso image

Tags: iso

Ive been trying to install Comsol Multiphysics on Ubuntu from a ISO I already mounted with FuriusMount but I cannot complete it. Maybe I am doing something wrong.
In the image I am showing the files I have in the mounted directory:

Folder with files from iso mounted image

[image]

Comment: Please paste the commands you used to install or run it...

Comment: @George I mounted the ISO with FuriusMount, but I just dont know how to proceed next..

Comment: Please look at the installation guide here: chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://www.comsol.com/shared/downloads/products/COMSOL_InstallationGuide.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is an old thread, but maybe some people will find it useful. You can install COMSOL in Windows/Linux/macOS from the same DVD.
In the case of Ubuntu, go to the mounted ISO or DVD via terminal and type:

```
./setup
```

The installation window will then appear.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the installation for Windows. You need to use the installation for Linux.

You can get the installer for Linux from the Comsol website:
https://www.comsol.com/product-download

*and select the appropriate options (version of Comsol and type of operation system Linux/Windows/MacOS)
If you are performing the download on a windows computer then standard settings will make you automatically download the iso for windows)*

Using this link you will go to the specific site to download the Linux version but you may still wish to change the Comsol version depending on your license:
https://www.comsol.com/product-download/5.3/linux

Comment: But that should not be a problem when you are dealing with Wine for .exe files

Comment: @Ornendil, Wine (Wine Is Not an Emulator) is not the same as windows. Lots of things are likely to fail when you try to install a complex program like Comsol on Linux using Wine. It is very simple to download the Linux version. I haven't tried it but I guess that it is very difficult to make Comsol (the Windows version) work in wine (If you love wine this much then maybe you should reconsider your choice of operation system and go back to Windows). *The standard way to install Comsol on Linux is to use the Linux version. There is no need to use Wine*